# Where can I get the route action in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework2

This is my `module.config.php`

```
return [
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'rotation',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

And this is my add.phtml.

```
<?php

  $form = $this->form;
  $form->setAttribute('action',
  $this->url('home/default', //your route name ...
    array('controller'=>'rotation', 'action' => 'add'))); 
  $form->prepare();

   echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
   echo $this->formRow($form->get('profilename'));
   echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

In line `$this->url('home/default', //your route name ...
        array('controller'=>'rotation', 'action' => 'add')));` I get a error. It doesn't display anything but when I erased that line it displays the textboxes.

My question is the url I put inside the code is correct or wrong? Thanks

Comment: For one thing to generate that route url with `url` helper you don't need pass in any parameters. Also just `$this->url('home')` should do. If you mention errors on stackoverflow, always remember to provide the error message and/or stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you very much that's worked after 2 hours of searching. Thank u

Comment: I've posted it as an answer with some more details. Good luck with ZF2 development! It can be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing to generate that route url with url helper you don't need pass in any parameters, because you've specified them in the `defaults` under `options`. Also since it's a literal I don't think you could even change the action (it's not variable for this type of route). 
Sidenote: you don't need to pass in the whole route class name, because ZF2 already has it registered under `Literal` (case-insensitive), so you can shorten the value of `type` key.

`$this->url('home')` should return the result you're expecting.

Comment: An `action` is definitely variable for a `Literal` route. That is why it is called `defaults`. You can provide other actions when dispatching the route and also overwrite the default action in `child_routes` or when dispatching those child routes.